# how to remove redirect loop during 404 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using following htaccess file for removing .php extension and adding trailing slashes at the end of the urls. It is working fine.

But the problem is that after adding this htaccess file to my site it is giving a redirection loop on any 404 error.

Moreover if i add ErrorDocument 404 anypage.php   then it is giving 500 internal server error.

Is there any way to solve these problems and getting correct htaccess file with following features.

Remove .php extension
Add trailing slashes
Successful redirection to homepage on  404 error

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Enable `RewriteLog` and show its output here.